# Passing dynamic log file name to log4j.properties in python

Tags: python, variables, logging, log4j, logfile

I can find the answer to this in Java, but so far I haven't seen a Python solution so I'm posting this question.

In my log4j.properties, I have:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,LOGFILE
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=log/${scriptname}.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```

In script.py in my main, I call a method to launch spark:

```
spark_submit(yarn_pool, os.path.basename(__file__))
```

Which is defined here:

```
def spark_submit(yarn_pool, scriptname):
   spark_submit_command = 'spark2-submit'
   ret_code = subprocess.call([
        spark_submit_command,
        '--master', 'yarn',
        '--queue', yarn_pool,
        '--executor-memory', '16g',
        '--driver-java-options', f'-Dlog4j.debug=true -Dlogfile.name={scriptname}'
```

Late in script.py, I attempt the logging:

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("My App")
spark = SparkContext(conf=conf)

log4jLogger = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger("root.logger")
LOGGER.warn("Starting App")
```

I'm trying to find a way to pass the filename of my script into the spark_submit method, and then into log4j.properties, but I cannot figure out the syntax to get the code to actually recognize my scriptname parameter.

I've tried ${sys:scriptname} and ${env:scriptname} as well, and those are also unrecognized. There doesn't seem to be clear documentation on how variables through all these files are passed together, and I'd appreciate help in understanding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${...}` variables in the `log4j.properties` file are expanded using Java system properties.

So if, in your `log4j.properties` file, you have

```
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=log/${scriptname}.log
```

you should be able to provide a value for `scriptname` using

```py
f'-Dscriptname={scriptname}'
```